# Calculate Time durations for each agent id, agentstatusid, date ----- sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, group-by

Having a table like below:

```
Agentid.   availabilitystatusid.      createdtime
93.        1                     2020-02-16 19:59:34.347
88         1                     2020-02-16 17:55:16.663
1          1                     2020-02-16 16:11:34.100
88         9                     2020-02-16 12:10:37.101
88         3                     2020-02-16 12:08:20.678
88.        1                     2020-02-16 12:04:35.567
93.        5                     2020-02-16 11:59:00.789
88.        7                     2020-02-08 20:08:09.654
67         4                     2020-02-08 13:34:45.476 
......
.....
```

Image below:

[image: Table like this - Limited data though]

Data contains different

1. Agentid's,
2. 13 different availabilitystatusid's (like online, ready, break, prayer time,work assigned etc.) and
3. Dates from 2019'aug to 2020'feb.

What I am looking for is:

```
Agentid.   availabilitystatusid.   date.            duration (in hours)
88.            1                   2020-02-16       0.2
88             3                   2020-02-16       3
1              7                   2020-02-03.      8
....
..
```

For each Agentid, for each statusid, for each date I need duration in hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How will you calculate duration ? Like taking differenece from dates. Let say you have three dates of the same day so what will be the logic to calculate hours

Comment: How should the calcuation of duration be done?

Comment: Please post your data (and code) as formatted text - not as images.

Comment: How do you handle periods that span days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function `lead()` to get the `createdtime` of the "next" record, and then aggregate.

This gives you the overall time each agent spent in each status:

```
select
    agentid,
    availabilitystatusid,
    sum(datediff(hour, createdtime, lead_createdtime)) duration_hours
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lead(createdtime) 
            over(partition by agentid order by createdtime) lead_createdtime
    from mytabe t
) t
group by agentid, availabilitystatusid
```

Assuming that periods do not span across several days - or that you want to bind duration to the day when the period started, you can do:

```
select
    agentid,
    availabilitystatusid,
    sum(datediff(hour, createdtime, lead_createdtime)) duration_hours,
    date(createdtime) created_day
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lead(createdtime) 
            over(partition by agentid order by createdtime) lead_createdtime
    from mytabe t
) t
group by agentid, availabilitystatusid, date(createdtime)
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I was validating with my data I saw a discrepancy like below
**Your Code yields**: 1165 mins (i took the privilege to convert for validation purposes) for Agentid=14 & availabilitystatusid=1 & created_day='2019-07-12'. 
I took all the data from my table for the above scenario:
14 2 05:18:20 (2019-07-12 for all entries) 
14 1 05:21:40
14 2 05:23:32
14 1 05:28:40
14 2 06:17:08
14 10 06:18:10
14 1 11:51:00
**Ans that I want is**: For agentid 14, statusid=1, duration= 46.3mins(~0.77hrs) [(6:17:08-5:28:40) + (5:23:32-5:21:40)]. 
Similarly for 2=9.6mins,10=~333mins